# Receive image through ajax post request what should be the class to receive that image

Tags: c#, ajax, model-view-controller

here is my ajax method

```
 fl = new FormData();

    fl.append("abcd", $("#so_camera_click")[0].files[0]);
 debugger;  

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../SaleOrder/AddSaleOrderToDB",
        dataType: "json",
        traditional: true,
        data: {

            f:fl,


        }});
```

and C# controller is

the id **so_camera_click** is `<input type="file" accept="image/*"/>` every time i debug javascript there is data in **fl** variable  but when it hits back end c# controller it gets null

```
       public JsonResult AddSaleOrderToDB(HttpPostedFileWrapper f)
             {
             }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your ajax request,
Change the value of data as follows,

```
  $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../SaleOrder/AddSaleOrderToDB",
        traditional: true,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false
        data: fl
        });
```

Use Proper, readable field names.
Your controller is expecting a File and not a JSON data.

Comment: how to add "IFromFile" class

Comment: IFormFile is provided by dotnet, which version are you using?

Comment: In Ajax,
  data: fl

Comment: yes in ajax request type is mentioned as post and  it is hitting c# modal but looses the data

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179617/discussion-between-code-name-jack-and-ricky).

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to post `FileData` and not `json`.

Additionally, for the Controller to map your posted values the argument must have the same name as you have used for the POST.

So for your example to work you'll have to do something like this

```
fl = new FormData();

fl.append("file", $("#so_camera_click")[0].files[0]);
debugger;  

$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "../SaleOrder/AddSaleOrderToDB",
     data: fl,
     contentType: false,
     processData: false
});
```

And in your Controller

```
public JsonResult AddSaleOrderToDB(HttpPostedFileWrapper file)
{
}
```

Comment: Illegal invocation this error is generated by jquery

Comment: Check my updated answer. Set `processData` and `contentType` to false